# How to setup Travis with Yarn Workspaces and Cypress

Tags: npm, continuous-integration, travis-ci, yarnpkg, lerna

I have a yarn workspaces/lerna monorepo and added cypress to it. Now I want to run my unit tests and cypress e2e tests in the travis pipeline.

Currently I have this travis config:

```
language: node_js
addons:
  apt:
    packages:
      - libgconf-2-4

cache:
  yarn: true
  directories:
    - node_modules
    - $HOME/.cache

notifications:
  email: false

node_js:
  - '13.6.0'

install:
  - yarn
  - yarn build

branches:
  except:
    - /^v\d+\.\d+\.\d+$/

stages:
  - test:unit
  - test:e2e

branches:
  except:
    - /^v\d+\.\d+\.\d+$/

e2e_defaults: &e2e_defaults
  script:
    - yarn e2e:ci
    - kill $(jobs -p) || true

jobs:
  include:
    - stage: test:unit
      script:
        - yarn test
    - stage: test:e2e
      env:
        - STAGE_NAME="4x-electron on Travis CI"
      <<: *e2e_defaults
    - stage: test:e2e
      env:
        - STAGE_NAME="4x-electron on Travis CI"
      <<: *e2e_defaults
    - stage: test:e2e
      env:
        - STAGE_NAME="4x-electron on Travis CI"
      <<: *e2e_defaults
    - stage: test:e2e
      env:
        - STAGE_NAME="4x-electron on Travis CI"
      <<: *e2e_defaults
```

However this is failing at:

```
lerna notice cli v3.20.2
lerna info ci enabled
lerna notice filter including "example"
lerna info filter [ 'example' ]
lerna ERR! EFILTER No packages remain after filtering [ 'example' ]
```

The executed script is `"start": "lerna --scope example run start",` which works fine on my machine. The same happens when using this as `yarn workspace example run start`, it throws something like `Cannot find module example`.

Note: I had to add `$HOME/.cache` to keep the Cypress binary. Cypress recommends not putting `node_modules` in there, but I feel like my modules are lost somewhere in between, so tried this without any success.

Please help :D

Comment: What is the exact name of the example package in its package.json? Check to make sure the case sensitivity matches exactly.  :)